# Elongated hexagon shaped button using only one element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, pseudo-element

I would like to make a button like these one just with CSS without using another element.

Button Image

[image]

Since the button has a `border` attached, I think I normally need both, the `:before` and `:after` elements to create just one arrow at one side. So to make one arrow at each side I would need another `span` element inside the link.

The second method I tried is the one you see below. But with this solution they are not properly centered and each side of the arrow is different in length.

Has someone a solution?

```css
/* General Button Style */

.button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e04e5e;
  margin: 40px auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Button Border Style */

.button.border {
  border: 4px solid #e04e5e;
}
.button.border:hover {
  background: #e04e5e;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Button Ribbon-Outset Border Style */

.button.ribbon-outset.border:after,
.button.ribbon-outset.border:before {
  top: 50%;
  content: " ";
  height: 43px;
  width: 43px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #fff;
}
.button.ribbon-outset.border:after {
  left: -3px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #e04e5e;
  border-left: 4px solid #e04e5e;
  transform: rotate(57.5deg) skew(30deg);
}
.button.ribbon-outset.border:before {
  right: -46px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 4px solid #e04e5e;
  border-right: 4px solid #e04e5e;
  transform: rotate(57.5deg) skew(30deg);
}
.button.ribbon-outset.border:hover:after {
  background: #e04e5e
}
.button.ribbon-outset.border:hover:before {
  background: #e04e5e
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me!</a>
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sKamk)

Comment: Maybe you can use an SVG background image and add it with data url.

Comment: @Harry I think your comment was still useful, also if its not exactly what I needed because its with further markup. Still interesting, thanks for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another alternate way to get this done with only one element.

This approach works like below:

1. Two pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` which are about half the size (including `borders`) of the main `.button` element. The height of each pseudo-element is 34px + 4px border on one side (top/bottom) and 2px on the other side.
2. The top half of the shape is achieved using the `:before` element whereas the bottom half is achieved using the `:after` element.
3. Using a `rotateX` with `perspective` to achieve the tilted effect and positioning to place the two elements such that they form the expected shape.

```css
/* General Button Style */

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e04e5e;
  margin: 40px auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button:before,
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 34px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button:before {
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
}
.button:after {
  top: 40px;
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
}

/* Button Border Style */

.button.border:before,
.button.border:after {
  border: 4px solid #e04e5e;
}
.button.border:before {
  border-bottom: none; /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}
.button.border:after {
  border-top: none; /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}

/* Button hover styles */

.button.border:hover:before,
.button.border:hover:after {
  background: #e04e5e;
}
.button.border:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me!</a>
```

[Fixed Width Demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/tsLza) | [Dynamic Width Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/veuc78af/)

**Output Screenshot:**

[image]

This is tested in Chrome v24+, Firefox v19+, Opera v23+, Safari v5.1.7, IE v10.

---

As-is, this would degrade quite well in IE 8 and IE 9 into a square button with borders. However, due to the nullification of one `border` (`border-bottom` for `:before` and `border-top` for `:after`) it would leave a white area (resembling a strike-through line) in the middle. This can be overcome by adding a couple of IE < 10 specific styles using conditional comments like in [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/#/pikomodanevo/2/edit).

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    .button.border:after{
      top: 38px;
    }
    .button.border:hover:before, .button.border:hover:after {
      border-bottom: 4px solid #e04e5e;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**Output Screenshot from IE 9 and IE 8:**

[image]

Comment: I really like your solution, didn't thought in perspective transforming, but I think for this kind of effect its the best to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For IE 9 you can use `-ms-` prefix.

Comment: This is a really nice approach, as you can control border and border-radius. However, as seen in your Dynamic Width demo, as the width changes, the two sides become different. Wish it can keep the same angle.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a simpler alternative to Harry's answer.

This approach uses `scale()` and `rotate(45deg)` transforms. Using this approach, you can very easily change the angle of right and left chevrons.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gqsk1L9/)**

```css
div {
    height: 70px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border-top: 4px solid #E04E5E;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #E04E5E;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #E04E5E;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
div:before, div:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 4px solid #E04E5E;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8,1.25) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8,1.25) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8,1.25) rotate(45deg);
    transform: scale(0.8,1.25) rotate(45deg);
}
div:before {
    left: -22px;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}
div:after {
    right: -22px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
}
div:hover, div:hover:before, div:hover:after {
    background-color: #E04E5E;
    color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div>HELLO!</div>
```

Want a wider arrow? Simply decrease `scale()` transform's `x` value **: [Fiddle (wide)](http://jsfiddle.net/n0r6k1eL/)**

Narrower one? Increase `scale()` transform's `x` value **: [Fiddle (narrow)](http://jsfiddle.net/j41qv17L/)**

---

**Note:** IE 8 and below don't support CSS Transforms (9 supports with `-ms-` prefix), so you can check out this site for supporting them: **[IE Transform Translator](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/)**

Comment: Nice alternate approach. But I don't quite agree with the simpler part because as indicated in my other comment, both involves calculations. In this approach, the scale value needs to be modified whereas in the other the rotation angle needs to be modified. Also both scale and skew would result in the borders becoming thicker/thinner.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your Pen

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/kEqep)

The essential changes are that I removed the side borders from the main button (as they were superflous

```
/* Button Border Style */
.button.border {
    border-top: 4px solid #e04e5e;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #e04e5e;
}
```

and changed a couple of values to tweak it all into place

```
/* Button Ribbon-Outset Border Style */
.button.ribbon-outset.border:after,
.button.ribbon-outset.border:before {
        top: 50%;
        content: " ";
        height: 43px;
        width: 43px;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
}

.button.ribbon-outset.border:after {
        left:0;
        margin-top:-40px;
        transform-origin:0 0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        border-bottom:4px solid #e04e5e;
        border-left:4px solid #e04e5e;
        transform:rotate(57.5deg) skew(30deg);
    }
    .button.ribbon-outset.border:before {
        right:-43px;
        margin-top:-40px;
        transform-origin:0 0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        border-top:4px solid #e04e5e;
        border-right:4px solid #e04e5e;
        transform:rotate(57.5deg) skew(30deg);
    }
```

Comment: great thanks, it looks clearly moore crisp. But there is still the problem that the corners of the arrows are not centered nor properly aligned: [See Image](http://i.imgur.com/edvu480.png) maybe its just not possible without further markup?

Comment: It's an issue due to the transform & skewing I suspect...that and subpixels. Frankly, I can't see a lot off difference unless I'm **really** zooming... **a lot**.

Comment: I can see it clearly, but I think it's hard if not impossible to get this right with CSS. Maybe you can just call it 'By design'. ;)

Comment: Frankly, I'm moving away from these effects towards inline SVG elements... **it's so much easier**.

Comment: Got it: [Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sKamk). Im unsure how to achieve the same with inline SVG elements due to the border.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer myself. It was a problem of the transform property of the :before and :after elements.

CSS changed:

```
/* Button Border Style */
.button.border {
    border-top:4px solid #e04e5e;
    border-bottom:4px solid #e04e5e;
}
/* Button Ribbon-Outset Border Style */
.button.ribbon-outset.border:after, .button.ribbon-outset.border:before {
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
}
.button.ribbon-outset.border:after {
    left:0;
    border-bottom:5px solid #e04e5e;
    border-left:5px solid #e04e5e;
    transform:rotate(45deg) skew(19deg,19deg);
}
.button.ribbon-outset.border:before {
    right:-42px;
    border-top:5px solid #e04e5e;
    border-right:5px solid #e04e5e;
    transform:rotate(45deg) skew(19deg,19deg);
}
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sKamk)

Comment: Good to see you have been able to solve it by yourself mate. Just in case you needed, [this demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/tsLza) has an alternate approach. *Note:* Tested only on Chrome.