# Creating hexagon shapes with list items

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have tried multiple options and tutorials, however, I am dealing with a Wordpress site and can only customize the HTML output so much for this nav menu... How can I make this work for these two menu items in the header?

I am dealing with list items, so this doesn't exactly work the same way as the post that I was penalized against for being a duplicate. It deals with only one element whereas I have links wrapped in li's that are part of the nav bar, so a bit different.

I want this:

[image]

and the HTML/SCSS I am working with (unsuccessfully) is below:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wsodI

```
<ul id="menu-right-menu-buttons" class="right-menu">
<li id="menu-item-8439" class="first-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8439"><a href="#">Businesses</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-8438" class="last-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8438"><a href="#">Job Seekers</a></li>
</ul>

.right-menu {
    float: right;

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: -100px;
        height: 20px; 
        border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
        border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
        border-bottom: 100px solid #021e4e;

        a {
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
        }
    }

    li:after {
        position: relative; 
        height: 0px; 
        width: 200px; 
        border-top: 100px solid #021e4e; 
        border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
        border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/
Scroll to where it says "hexagon"

Comment: tried that already, and tried rotating it accordingly so that it fits my shape requirements.. it doesn't come out right at all. Another issue is trying to get that white border over the shape...

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element?rq=1

Comment: Take a took at my update with the hexagon borders if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a triangle with the border property. You see a normal box like this if it has i.e 30px height 30px width and some border, lets give it 5px border

[image]

Now you see how the edges of the borders take form, then you can just give it height 0 and width 0 and you will have one side of the trapezium made by the borders to have length 0 so you have a triangle. Like this

[image]

Tha T is for top border, B for bottom border, R for fight border, and L for left bortder. Now you just give border color. You ca have R with color red and the other ones white and you will have a triangle pointing to the left. Same way with the L border.

Now you can use a div to be a normal rectangle and use pseudoselectors, :after and :before to give it some border and make your two triangles at the beginning and the end and you will have your hexagon

See the jsfiddle, I created an exagon for you with the border black to notice where the border is: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/o742jd86/

See the borders in `#hexagon:after` and `#hexagon:before`

This is the result:

[image]

UPDATE: If you want the borders you can just overlap one Hexagon with another one like in this jsfiddle in pure CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/o742jd86/1/

[image]

Here are two other options you can get that working with only one element. I took them from other answer to show better options here

http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/tsLza

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sKamk

[image]

Comment: The OP is clearly aware of this technique and has used it.

Comment: I don't get your downvote, you just focus on bothering people. You may get people downvoting you. It would be a shame

Comment: Yes it would but I didn't downvote.

Comment: The guy applied the technique but he got trapeziums not hexagons, so I explained it to him so he can understand it and get the hexagon. I also created a jsfiddle to show him the hexagon so I guess its not a bad answer.

Answer (score 2):

This was the best I was able to get with just plain CSS. It's not by any means perfect but hey...might be useful.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/bc9a5Lof/2/

the HTML:

```
<div id="hexagon"><div class="inner">Job Seekers</div>    </div>
```

(Note that I did add a div inside the link box. This is to get the white border.)

and the CSS:

```
body {
    padding:100px;
    background:#aaa;
}
#hexagon {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 54px;
    padding:3px 0;
    background:#fff;
    position: relative;
}
#hexagon .inner {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 54px;
    padding:0 20px;
    background: #021E4D;
    position: relative;
    color:#fff;
    font:16pt/54px Arial;
}
#hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid #fff;
}
#hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #fff;
}
#hexagon .inner:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -17px;
    top:1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 26px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 26px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17px solid #021E4D;
}
#hexagon .inner:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -17px;
    top:1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 26px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 26px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid #021E4D;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Feel free to shoot me any questions. :)

Comment: both yours and carlos were very helpful, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 canvas programming for drawing and filling purpose.

The best framework is which I am using, this is responsive and lightweight, you will get all the features of Bootstrap at 12KB(Zipped), and it is easy to understand. You will get page speed of 100 on mobiles too.

Check this: http://skhost.in/one

Click below to check the speed:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fskhost.in%2Fone&tab=desktop