# Hexagon CSS (Rectangle with "Arrow-effect")

Tags: css, css-shapes

Please see the following CSS rules I'm using right now to create a rectangle with "arrow-effect" left and right:

**CSS:**

```
.hexagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px; 
    height: 34.64px;
    background-color: #64C7CC;
    margin: 17.32px 0;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 17.32px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 17.32px solid #64C7CC;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

Can anyone help me out what to do when I need a rectangle with `width:60px` and `height:22px` and triangles left/right which fits?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element with a slightly different approach to generate a hexagon. The calculations are also relatively simple.

Comment: @michbeck Is that what you want? JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kweydhvL/1/

Comment: I am not shure I understand the exact aim of your question, could you clarify with an image of the shape you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @web-tiki: My understanding is that OP wants to know what should be the border-width (of the triangles) if the `.hexagon` elements height becomes 22px instead of the current 34.64px. Probably because math theorems is required to calculate the width of the triangular area's sides based on the height of the rectangular area.

Comment: @michbeck also check this one - http://jsfiddle.net/kweydhvL/2/

Comment: awesome guys, thank you very much! i prefer Mary Melody's solution -> http://jsfiddle.net/kweydhvL/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kweydhvL/2/)**

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 50px;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  left: 100%;
  border-left: 11px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  right: 100%;
  border-right: 11px solid #64C7CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```