# Oblique or twisted border shape

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I'm interested if it's possible to create wrapped (or maybe better said twisted) border using CSS. Effect I wanted to achieve is in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most easiest and neat solution would be to use `svg` to create the border.

[image]

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
#content {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -2 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 l-15,15 l15,15 h-200 l15,-15z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

---

You could even spice it up with some curves using quadratic curves.

[image]

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -1 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q-20,15 0,30 h-200 q20,-15 0,-30" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -1 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q0,10 -15,15 q10,0 15,15 h-200 q0,-10 15,-15 q-10,0 -15,-15" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="200" height="30" viewBox="-1 -1 201 33">
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q-10,0 -15,12.5 l15,2.5 l-15,2.5 q0,10 15,13 h-200 q10,0 15,-12.5 l-15,-2.5 l15,-2.5 q0,-10 -15,-12.5" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

---

You could easily add a drop shadow effect.

[image]

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="205" height="35" viewBox="-1 -1 205 38">
    <filter id="f">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" />
    </filter>
    <path filter="url(#f)" d="M0,0 h200 l-15,15 l15,15 h-200 l15,-15z" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,3)" fill="black" />
    <path id="shape" d="M0,0 h200 l-15,15 l15,15 h-200 l15,-15z" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="205" height="35" viewBox="-1 -1 205 38">
    <path filter="url(#f)" d="M0,0 h200 q0,10 -15,15 q10,0 15,15 h-200 q0,-10 15,-15 q-10,0 -15,-15" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,3)" fill="black" />
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q0,10 -15,15 q10,0 15,15 h-200 q0,-10 15,-15 q-10,0 -15,-15" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <svg width="205" height="35" viewBox="-1 -1 205 38">
    <path filter="url(#f)" d="M0,0 h200 q-10,0 -15,12.5 l15,2.5 l-15,2.5 q0,10 15,13 h-200 q10,0 15,-12.5 l-15,-2.5 l15,-2.5 q0,-10 -15,-12.5" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,3)" fill="black" />
    <path d="M0,0 h200 q-10,0 -15,12.5 l15,2.5 l-15,2.5 q0,10 15,13 h-200 q10,0 15,-12.5 l-15,-2.5 l15,-2.5 q0,-10 -15,-12.5" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively you could always use `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements.

The `width` and `height` of the `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements were calculated using some basic trigonometry.

[image]

The `opposite side` is the `width` and `height` of the `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements. The one on the left is given top and right borders and the one on the right is given top and left borders. Then, the one on the left has been rotated `45deg` and the one on the right has been rotated `-45deg`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 21.21px;
  height: 21.21px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 1px;
  left: -9px;
}
div:after {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: You could use SVG, but OP asked for CSS ;)

Comment: @SW4 - I think this is the easiest and flexible solution. :)

Comment: Its not bad by any means, and has other advantages- but works on the assumption OP can change their HTML (as opposed to just the styling), and is relatively au-fait with SVG

Comment: Good alternate (and I personally like it) but I tend to concur with SW4 as OP had not tagged SVG.

Comment: @Harry - Sure. I'll add a CSS solution as well. :)

Comment: @SW4 - I have not copied anyone's answer, right hand to the god. Haven't even looked at anyone's answer yet.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py - with the exception of minor differences, the core tenet of the CSS answer, is identical to that posted earlier in another answer- using pseudo answers, and rotating them. A such it is not an original solution.

Comment: @SW4  -I will add a complete explanation on how I got that shape if you don't believe me!

Comment: Compare: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27720277/404335, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27720208/revisions

Comment: @SW4 - Dude! Just wait I'm adding a complete explaination on how I got that shape, just to prove you that you are wrong!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: @SW4 - The way I started working on CSS solution was I copied my original CSS code that I already had. I swear to GODDDDDDDDDDDD!!!!!!

Comment: I like the SVG solution the most, as far it's simple and flexible, however, there's a problem with text displaying in IE, any possible solution?

Comment: @JohnyGomez - Ive updated the snippets, this will work on IE as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this **purely in CSS** by manipulating the `:before` and `:after` psuedo elements.

The key advantages are that you can keep your HTML 'as is', and it maintains a strict seperation of concerns between content (`html`) and styling (`CSS`).

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div:after {
  right: -23px;
}
div:before {
  left: -23px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: I agree, this solution 100% fulfills the task, however it was posted little later than chipChocolate answer :)

Comment: @JohnyGomez - If you look at the revision history- this was posted first and the CSS part of this answer was added to chipChocolates, however the SVG solution is original. Important above all else is you have an answer :)

Comment: @SW4 sorry I didn't notice that :) thank you for this solution, probably I will use it in my project

Answer (score 4):

This is a different approach using pure CSS alone to achieve this effect (using the method explained in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element/25448974#25448974) answer but reverse rotation of elements).

[image]

Basically it involves two pseudo elements that are rotated with a bit of perspective and positioned one below the other to achieve the shape.

This approach works like below:

1. Two pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` which are roughly about half the size (including borders) of the main `.button` element. The height of each pseudo-element is 35.5px + 3px border on one side (top/bottom) and 1.5px on the other side (because the two overlap at half distance).
2. The top half of the shape is achieved using the `:before` element whereas the bottom half is achieved using the `:after` element.
3. Using a `rotateX` with perspective to achieve the tilted effect and positioning to place the two elements such that they form the expected shape.

> **Note:** There is a bit of extra styling for a sample `hover` effect which causes the shape to turn into an elongated hexagon. This is not part of the question but is added just for sample (and a bit of fun :)). Also, older versions of Chrome and Safari seems to be giving incorrect output for the `hover` behavior whereas the latest versions of all browsers are doing fine.

[image]

```css
/* General Button Style */

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  margin: 40px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button:before,
.button:after {
  width: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 35.5px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}
.button:before {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.button:after {
  border-top: none;
}
.button:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
}
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35.5px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
}
/* Hover Styles */

.button:hover:before,
.button:hover:after {
  background: #000;
}
.button:hover:before {
  top: -3px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
}
.button:hover:after {
  top: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
}
.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

As-is, this would degrade quite well in IE 8 and IE 9 into a square button with borders. However, due to the nullification of one `border` (`border-bottom` for `:before` and `border-top` for `:after`) it would leave a white area (resembling a strike-through line) in the middle. This can be overcome by adding a couple of IE < 10 specific styles using conditional comments like in this demo.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style>
        .button:after{
            top: 38px;
        }
        .button:hover:before, .button:hover:after {
            border-bottom: 4px solid black;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**Output Screenshots from IE 9 and IE 8:** (both normal and during hover)

[image]

[image]