# Hexagon with information?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am working on My Profile button for my website and this is what I want:

[image]

(Taken from a game). How would I make those Energy, Health and Experience in CSS and HTML?

My current progress: http://play.futuretechs.eu/index.php/myprofile

[image]

I don't need the text, only those going out lines.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please consider adding relevant code within questions, in order for others to be able to provide appropriate answers.

Comment: This might help you with some ideas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element/25448974#25448974. At the moment the question is a bit broad because there are atleast 3 different shapes in the image.

Comment: you must include the code of what you tried so far and mention what you got upon your tryings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.css-shapes-preview {
    position: relative;
    height: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #428BCA;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-shapes-preview"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! And how i would mirror that so i would have only 1 div? (The same would be on the left side)

Comment: Okey, i was pretty dumb...