# Rectangle with pointed ends that change colour on hover

Tags: css

I have found on this website a example that fits my needs except one thing. If i add hover, the left and right triangles will have the same colour instead of the new hover colour. Any idea how to have black triangles when we hover over rectangle?

```css
.yourButton {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
.yourButton:hover {background-color:black}
.yourButton:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:40px solid blue;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
}

.yourButton:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:40px solid blue;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="yourButton">You wanted this?</div>
```

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element/25448974#25448974. Won't say duplicate because the approaches are different but you can use the method mentioned in that linked answer. For your current approach, just change the `border` colors of `:after` and `:before` on `hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 different hover class for `:after` and `:before` and change the border color.

```css
.yourButton {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
.yourButton:hover {background-color:black}
.yourButton:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:40px solid blue;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
}

.yourButton:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:40px solid blue;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
}


.yourButton:hover:after{
   border-left:40px solid #000;
}
.yourButton:hover:before{
  border-right:40px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="yourButton">You wanted this?</div>
```