# Shape in css and responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have this shape:

[image]

It is an image but i need it in css only and responsive, is it possible?

I need the exact same one in the image.

Comment: have you tried googling css shapes?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element/25448974?s=1|3.2109#25448974

Comment: The following link shows how to create a hexagon using css. https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Show us, what you've tried already!

Comment: I see only the use of pixels in most of them, and i want to do some changes to the inner background so....

Comment: @totothegreat that comment doesn't help at all! Specify exactly what you want and show us what you have tried to archive this.

Comment: plusOne to motivate you keep asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions. The first one that comes to mind is constructing it from multiple divs and using skew() for example:

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="skew-left red"></div>
    <div class="skew-right red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="skew-left red"></div>
    <div class="skew-right red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.top,
.bottom,
.red {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}

.skew-left,
.skew-right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.bottom {
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.skew-left {
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.skew-right {
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0mx4ykh/

There are other solutions though and some of them have been discussed here already. Check the links others gave you in the comments.