# how to create an elongated hexagon input field

Tags: css

How can i create an input field like image below with css only styling?
[image]

Comment: This thread has a similar shape (but is not an input field) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element/25448974?s=1|4.7898#25448974. You would get some ideas from there. The problem with input field is that you can't add any pseudo elements to it. You would most likely have to use wrapper elements and style them like in that answer.

Comment: i already saw that example but i do not succeed in it to change it to an input field