# CSS - Add a hexagonal border on text

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is there a way to add a hexagonal border around html text?  The border above and below seem like normal CSS borders, however the left and right borders are angled. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: This one could help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422524/css-responsive-elongated-hexagon-with-text-and-gradient-background-border/36423312#36423312

Comment: [This tool](http://csshexagon.com/) looks helpful, as well as [this resource](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing us what you've tried.

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/570/

Comment: @paulie_d Provided answer not work in MS Edge, maybe this cross browser example could help you. http://codepen.io/isaactzab/pen/pyZgWp