# Rounded corner with pointy edge on button CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am thinking of using pseudo elements before and after in button to achieve this rounded-sides-triangle (rotated) and pointy corner. See photo for desired result.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920706/css-hexagonal-button-with-rounded-corners

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS hexagonal button with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920706/css-hexagonal-button-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: My output is more or less the same with the answer given by Eugine but not exactly the same as the "roundiness" of the radius maintaining the pointy border

Comment: @Ironman, It is not the duplicate. the reference, you give is, can be achieved using radius and rotate. It is not the case of this question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  --c: #000;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) top/100% 50% no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box:before {
  border-radius: 60px 60px 0 0;
}

.box:after {
  border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
  background-position:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Temani, thanks I appreciate this. But I am putting text over it the color seems to be above the text. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check on.

```css
.padding { padding: 20px 50px }
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    height: 51px;
    background: #aaa;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.box:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -23px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    height: 43px;
    background: #aaa;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 21px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(8deg, 8deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(8deg, 8deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(8deg, 8deg);
}
.box:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: -23px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    height: 43px;
    background: #aaa;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 21px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(8deg, 8deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(8deg, 8deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(8deg, 8deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="padding">
<div class="box"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: My output is somewhat the same as this but i am aiming for the radius that is more like a circle but maintain the pointy.