# How to create triangle's form with inputs and button?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

Now I have a form like above but without triangles on the left and right sides. I have imlemented this feature to my form, but it turned some static, not adaptive(I selected sizes by means pixels with considering only my browser ). I'll be very glad if you provide me some links. This triangle form have triangle shadow accordingly, so i can't use :after and :before. It most important

Comment: Yes, and with box-shadow

Comment: maybe you could make a copy of the element's shape and put it below the element to make a shadow effect if you cant use pseudo selectors

Comment: @MarikZuckor Is it your purpose?

Comment: you could use gradients like in your previous question, same shape ...

Comment: i dont want to read this text. is it mnogo bukaff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use CSS-transforms. The main idea is described in [Elongated hexagon shaped button using only one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element).

You can add box-shadow directly to .rhombus:before and :after (but I've noticed some issues in Mozilla) or just make another wrapper with offset and copy of those pseudo-elements.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
form .header {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: -10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
form input,
form button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #FFD900;
}
.rhombus {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.rhombus:before,
.rhombus:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1E9BAF;
  z-index: -1;
}
.rhombus:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  /*box-shadow: 3px 5px #DDD;*/
}
.rhombus:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  /*box-shadow: 5px 5px #DDD;*/
}
```

```html
<form class="rhombus">
<div class="header">ОСТАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ</div>
<input name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"/>
<input name="phone" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона"/>
<button type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только вот не очень оно настраиваемое, например при двойном box shadow 0 0 0 2px, 0 0 0 6px, который нужен, оно ломает верстку, хотя и так и сяк пробовал, без толку. можно как-то без transform обойтись здесь?или только так?

Comment: Если нужна двойная полоса по периметру, то можно добавить смещение вверх и вниз (а так же вправо и влево для компенсации искажения от поворота). Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/u88qb4wh/2/ Как добиться этого без трансформации я не придумал. Может быть, что-то можно сделать градиентами, как предлагалось в другом ответе.

Answer (score 0):

You can create triangle shape using CSS border like this example

```css
.form {
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #1E9BAF;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: -7px 15px 0px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.triangle, 
.triangle > div {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 40px solid transparent;
}

.leftTriangle {    
    left: -55px;
    border-right: 15px solid #1E9BAF;
}

.leftTriangle > div {
  left: -42px;
  top: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}   

.rightTriangle {
    right: -55px;
    border-left: 15px solid #1E9BAF;
}

.rightTriangle > div {
  right: -28px;
  top: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <div class="triangle leftTriangle">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle rightTriangle">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

similar answer to your previous qusetion :). 4 gradients + `background-size` can also do the job here :

```css
form {
  font-size:2em;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-250deg, transparent 1em, #1E9BAF 1.01em) top left no-repeat, 
    linear-gradient( 70deg, transparent 1em, #1E9BAF 1.01em) bottom left no-repeat, 
    linear-gradient( 250deg, transparent 1em, #1E9BAF 1.01em) top right no-repeat, 
    linear-gradient( -70deg, transparent 1em, #1E9BAF 1.01em) bottom right no-repeat;
  background-size: 60% 50.3%;
  box-shadow:0 1.25em 15px -1.25em ;
  background-size: 60% 50%;
  margin: 2em;
  padding:0.5em;
  text-align: center
}
label{display:block;color:white }
[type] {background:linear-gradient(to top, #ffab00, #fff800);}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>texting</label>
  <input placeholder=" Name"/> <input placeholder="☎ phone"/> <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

[updated pen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KzJMNQ)