# Inability to use hexagonal or round submit buttons in nativescript for android

Tags: angular2-nativescript

With some little research done, i found out that makings rounds button and color patches could be done with the Clip Path but am not still understanding the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Nativescript just uses web technologies, so you should be using HTML for function and css for styling, so for a hexagonal Submit button, how about this:

### Option 1

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px; 
  height: 51.96px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 25.98px 0;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 45px solid transparent;
  border-right: 45px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 25.98px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 25.98px solid #64C7CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

## Option 2

You can just fall back on the Unicode char, e.g.

```
<span style="color: #6C6; font-size: 135px;">&#x2B22;</span>
```

Then with either of those overlay your anchor tag, button, input etc. with the text you want. The advantage with the first solution is it doesn't interfere with your font selection and is more widely compatible, however, the second is much neater.

If you need more styling options, you can use images as backgrounds in the first option. See [here](http://csshexagon.com/) for more details on customization options.

A similar approach of using css to style a circle would be best. Usually you set rounded corners to equal a radius half the elements width.

## Option 3

```css
/* General Button Style */

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #e04e5e;
  margin: 40px auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button:before,
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 34px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button:before {
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
}
.button:after {
  top: 40px;
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
}

/* Button Border Style */

.button.border:before,
.button.border:after {
  border: 4px solid #e04e5e;
}
.button.border:before {
  border-bottom: none; /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}
.button.border:after {
  border-top: none; /* to prevent the border-line showing up in the middle of the shape */
}

/* Button hover styles */

.button.border:hover:before,
.button.border:hover:after {
  background: #e04e5e;
}
.button.border:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button ribbon-outset border">Click me!</a>
```

When you start searching for web solutions, you'll find it much easier to get answers, e.g. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element) answer for the final snippet.