# Elongated hexagon shaped button for Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-shapes

How to make Bootstrap 4 buttons with hexagonal left & right sides, similar to below image?

[image]

Here are answers to a similar question, but copying those styles in Bootstrap 4 (with proper .btn classes) doesn't work properly:
[Elongated hexagon shaped button using only one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445118/elongated-hexagon-shaped-button-using-only-one-element)

Comment: Instead of copying, have you tried understanding the code and *adapting* to make it fir your needs? Have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in a comment by @chriskirknielsen, please understand code first and changes the code by your need.

```css
body {
    /* JUST FOR STYLING */
    background-color: #3c93af !important;
}

.custom_btn {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffdc01;
    margin: 40px auto;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.custom_btn:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.custom_btn:before,
.custom_btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: -1;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.custom_btn:before {
    transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(3deg);
}

.custom_btn:after {
    top: 40px;
    transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-3deg);
}

.custom_btn.custom_btn--border:before,
.custom_btn.custom_btn--border:after {
    border: 4px solid #ffdc01;
}

.custom_btn.custom_btn--border:before {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.custom_btn.custom_btn--border:after {
    border-top: none;
}

.custom_btn.custom_btn--border:hover:before,
.custom_btn.custom_btn--border:hover:after {
    background: #ffdc01;
}

.custom_btn.custom_btn--border:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a href="#" class="custom_btn custom_btn--border">Click me!</a>
```